# How to get repository folder in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

With the below option we are able to checkout a git repository to a different folder.

[image]

But how to access this folder value?
Is there any variable for that?
$Workspace will point to the work space folder where the default repo cloning is being done, but not this location.

Is there any other variable to access this?

So I can use the same in subsequent build steps.

Answer (score 1):

By using this additional behavior The code will be cloned relative to the workspace folder. So you have to use **$Workspace** environment variable for locating the code directory.

[image]
Now , to your requirement is to use the same code repo in  subsequent builds, you can add Multiple build steps in the same job .

[image]

Another way is to create a **pipeline** for defining consecutive build steps.

Comment: But my repo is not relative to workspace directory.
And we specifically mentioned that as I shown in screenshot.We have our own reasons for that.

How to get that folder name in some variable then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom workspace (your job > advanced > use custom work space), then access the workspace variable as usual e.g. for a batch command use %WORKSPACE%